# Случайная конвертация числа в восьмеричную систему

Tags: python, syntax

Есть некий список строк где все элементы имеют вид:
"a+-b+-c+-d=e", где a, b, c, d, e - двузначные числа.
Мне надо оставить только верные равенства, проблема в том, что иногда мои a, b, c, d или e могут начинаться с нуля и питон считает его как число из 8ричной системы.

```html
for str in alt_strings:  
    if (eval(str[:11]) == int(str[12:])):
        print(str)
```

Comment: Указанный код как относится к проблеме?

Comment: Да, это собственно проход по списку строк. Именно тут ошибка.

Comment: А точнее недочет)

Comment: Проверять на наличие "08" и "09". Если есть, то использовать другой способ.

Comment: 03+27-30+16
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Вот что может быть

Comment: Значит на все проверять от 01 до 09. (во втором питоне до 07 нормально работает). Или ловить исключение и если поймал, то использовать другой способ.

Comment: Вот я и хотел узнать этот другой способ, использовать int() для всех чисел?

Comment: Разобрать строку на двузначные числа срезами.

Comment: а что тогда делать с мат. символами?

Comment: if ( str.startswith('0',0) or str.startswith('0',3) or str.startswith('0',6) or str.startswith('0',9) or str.startswith('0',12) )

Вот мое условие и мне пишет ошибку

Comment: тоже самое и с 
if ( str[0] == '0' or str[3] == '0' or str[6] == '0' or str[9] == '0' or str[12] == '0' )

Comment: Какую ошибку-то?

Comment: Кстати, str - встроенная функция. Не нужно так называть свои переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, проще сразу избавляться от ведущих нулей:

```
import re
expr = '03+20-14+08+1.0-0'
res=re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', expr)
print(res) # -> 3+20-14+8+1.0-0
```

Comment: спасибо, всё заработало